# Is there an app to verify my phone's camera sensor specs?

Tags: cameraphones, android, apps

As we all know, the sensor is the heart of a digital camera and especially so in a mobile phone since most other variables (F-Stop, zoom, ISO, aperture) are for the most part static.

There are a log of budget Chinese phones out there that *claim* impressive specifications, in terms of having Sony sensors and 13-20 MP cameras; however, when you look these numbers you see that for the same model the sensor is changed from Sony to some inferior brand and as a result all of the other stats are remarkably lower.

As there are benchmarks to test the phones hardware (`CPU-Z`), is there any software that can read your camera sensor brand reliably as well as access the actual quality (in terms of MP) in the camera?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works completely but another solution could be using a tool such as an [Exif Viewer](http://regex.info/exif.cgi) like that. You download the image from your phone to a computer and upload it to that or as another person said, view that on your personal computer. I don't know if this will give the exact camera, this can vary on how the phone/camera generates the data but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a file manager like ES File Manager and open the file located at /sys/android_camera/sensor, there you should find the model number of the camera sensor. Google it for details.

Comment: no I tried I tried a root file explorer but the whole thing is too confusing way too many links back pointing and the files are off no use to suggest what the image sensor would be
What I found out that helps hopefully w other phones as well, is this app called aida64. It brings out the sensor name.
The other way would be to get inside adb console and start messing around with a bunch of commands lsci etc

Comment: Will this work on a non-rooted phone?